# Files are created empty when using BufferReader and BufferWriter to write a file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to load a JSON from webservice and write it to a file using the following code:

```
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "texts");
cacheDir.mkdirs();
File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, "" + articleId);
try {
    if (!cacheFile.exists()) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            try {
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                // this approach fails
                /*
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cacheFile.getAbsolutePath()));

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
                writer.flush();
                reader.close();
                writer.close();
                */

                // this approach works
                Gson g = new Gson();
                Article article = g.fromJson(reader, Article.class);
                String json = g.toJson(article);

                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(cacheFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                out.print(json);

                out.flush();
                out.close();
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing JSON", e);
            } finally {
                c.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception parsing JSON", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked with adb shell and Android Monitor file browswer and the files seem to be created:

[image]

However, when I do `cat filename` from `adata/data/appdir/cache` no file content is printed (only command is printed again `cat filename`). What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: is your device rooted ?

Comment: I think yes, it's an emulator from `Genymotion`

Comment: get rid of `cacheFile.exists()`. Try debugging the content of the reader. Add some log to see if you are getting data back from the server. Do you have the internet permission ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, yes, content from the server comes OK, because I show it the first time if the file doesn't exist and it's displayed. It's second time when I see that the file exists I read from the file and not from the web. How would you advice me to debug it?

Comment: just add `Log.d("TEST", ": " + line)` in the while loop and read the output

Comment: @Blackbelt, thanks, just added it. `Log.d("TEST", ":z " + line);` outputs `D/TEST﹕ :z null`, so it seems that it can't read anything from `BufferedReader` so either it's empty or I'm using it in the wrong way, what do you think? It's also interesting that I have `Article article = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Article.class);` after that and article is correctly instantiated from the reader.

Comment: @Blackbelt, the problem is here `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {` - null is returned. I've worked around that issue converting to JSON and back to string (shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050065/printwriter-truncates-string-when-writing-to-file-why)) but it's probably inefficient. Can you please help me how to debug the problem with stream?

Comment: are you sure that the backend call is returning something valid? Can you check the http response code ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, yes, I'm sure, I've checked response code - it's 200, and as shown in my other question if I use this approach `String json = g.toJson(article);` everything works OK. I've added that piece to the code in this question with comments `this approach fails` and `this approach works` so you can see when it works OK. I think maybe `Gson` library does something to get valid output from `BufferredReader`?

Comment: I don't know why it is not working. You could try to use a char buffer to read from the input stream, instead of using readLine, in order to see if it makes any difference

Comment: @Blackbelt, I see, thanks anyway. At least I know that the code and approach is correct. _You could try to use a char buffer to read from the input stream_ - do you mean `char ch = (char) reader.read()`?

Comment: something like [this](https://gist.github.com/bblackbelt/920deffb5d3fbabf01a3). Can you give it a try and print the content of the StringBuffer after the for loop ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, this `Log.d("TEST", ":stringBuffer " + stringBuffer.toString());` outputted this `D/TEST﹕ :stringBuffer {"words":[{"id":"1","word":"In","isNewLineSymbol":"0","isPunctuati...`. (ellipsis is mine) Does it help?

Comment: well it looks like it is working. Now you just need to write the content on the file

Comment: @Blackbelt, thanks a lot! Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? I'm also wondering though why it didn't work with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use `readLine` to read from the InputStream, try with `read` and a `char[]`

```
if (in != null) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    final char[] charBuffer = new char[8 * 1024];
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), charBuffer.length);
    int read;  
    while ((read = reader.read(charBuffer)) != -1) {
         stringBuffer.append(charBuffer, 0, read);
    }
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(cacheFile.getAbsolutePath()));
    out.print(stringBuffer.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    reader.close();
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Article article = g.fromJson(stringBuffer.toString(), Article.class);
}
```

Comment: `fos.write(charBuffer, 0, read);` here I get the error `Wrong first argument - Found char[], required byte[]`, why is it there?

Comment: My bad. Change char[] to byte []

Comment: A bit of your help please... after I've read from buffer with `read = reader.read(charBuffer)) != -1` I pass the reader to `Gson` and do the followign `Article article = g.fromJson(reader, Article.class);`, however `fromJson` returns `null`, as if there is nothing to read from a `reader`. Is this a valid case to read from a reader and then pass it to the other method to work with it?

Comment: you can't reuse the reader again. Using the StringBuffer should fix it. I'll update my answer

Comment: I see, that's what I thought. Thanks a lot! Best luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all the operations inside

```
if (!cacheFile.exists()) {
   //your code here
}
```

The file.exists() method returns true if a file denoted by the path exists. So in effect what you are saying is 'do my operations if the file does not exist' which does not make sense.

Instead you could

```
if (!cacheFile.exists()) {
    cacheFile.createNewFile() 
}
//do the rest of your stuff here
```

Comment: Actually 'do my operations if the file does not exist' does make sense to me - if we don't have a copy of this file locally fetch it from the web - else use the cached version.

Comment: @Maximus - so you realise if there was something wrong with the code the first time you ran it the files now exists so you need to manually delete them each time in order to retest your debugged code?

Comment: The exists() method is misplaced IMO. An error in this method will create a file and after that it will never be written to because of the exists() clause. A good option would be to destroy() the file on error.

Comment: @Elemental, yeah, it's a test code, I'm going to clean it up when it's working :). Thanks!