# PrintWriter truncates string when writing to file, why?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing to a file using PrintWriter like this:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Article article = g.fromJson(reader, Article.class);
String json = g.toJson(article);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(cacheFile.getAbsolutePath()));
out.print(json);
```

However, the string in json is truncated when I see it in the file. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: did you flush and close the PrintWriter ?

Comment: I didn't, let me try with closing and flushing, thanks

Comment: @Blackbelt, thanks, it's working now! :) Do I always have to flush before closing?

Comment: `close()` usually takes of flushing the  internal  buffer. I call it always

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to close the PrintWriter using [PrintWriter#close() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29)

Add

```
out.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. You failed to close the file.

Comment: Thanks, let me try. What happens if I don't close it? Why only a part of string was written to the file?

Comment: @Maximus What happens? There might be still something in the "write buffer" and the resource is still bound.

Comment: What happens is undefined. Anything can happen, including nothing. You have to close anything that is closeable. You have to to release every acquired resource.

Comment: @EJP, I see, I'm just curios why it flushed only the part of the string. As I understand from _Anything can happen, including nothing_, it's hard to tell, right?

Comment: It's hard to tell what? Hard to tell what 'anything' is? Impossible, I would have said.